# Modern OpenGL 3.0: How to move a 2D vbo on screen

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I have been learning modern OpenGL (3.0) for a couple of weeks now and am trying to create a lunar lander clone in 2D. All tutorials and questions I have read so far did not help at all.

Vertexes in header and other OpenGL:

```
GLuint vertexArrayLander;
GLuint landerVBO;
GLfloat landerVertex [26] = {

        //Lander Body
           0.03f, 0.2f,
          (-0.03f), 0.2f,
          (-0.05f), 0.15f,
          (-0.05f), 0.1f,
          (-0.03f), 0.05f,

          (-0.045f), 0.0f,      //left leg
          (-0.029f), 0.05f,

          (0.029f), 0.05f,      //right leg
          (0.045f), 0.0f,

          0.03f, 0.05f,     
          0.05f, 0.1f,      
          0.05f, 0.15f,     
          0.03f, 0.2f

};
```

Constructor:

```
Lander::Lander() {    
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayLander);
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayLander);

glGenBuffers(1, &landerVBO);    
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, landerVBO);   
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(landerVertex), landerVertex,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
 }
```

Drawing works so far, but how do I apply x and y to my landerVbo without messing with the array directly? 
I have tried using glTranslatef(x,y,0.0f) which had no effect at all.

Drawing Method:

```
void Lander::drawLander() {
float x = position->getX();
float y = position->getY();

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, landerVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,           // attribute 0. No particular reason.
        2,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*) 0            // array buffer offset
        );


//draw all graphic elements

//How to apply x and y on all points?

glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0 , 13);
//vao

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

x and y are the position of the lander on screen.
What I want to draw is this pseudo code:

```
GLfloat landerVertex [26] = {

        //Lander Body
          x + 0.03f, y + 0.2f,
          x + (-0.03f), y + 0.2f,
          x + (-0.05f), y + 0.15f,
          x + (-0.05f), y + 0.1f,
          x + (-0.03f), y + 0.05f,

          x + (-0.045f), y + 0.0f,      //left leg
          x + (-0.029f), y + 0.05f,

          x + (0.029f), y + 0.05f,      //right leg
          x + (0.045f), y + 0.0f,

          x + 0.03f, y + 0.05f,     
          x + 0.05f, y + 0.1f,      
          x + 0.05f, y + 0.15f,     
          x + 0.03f, y + 0.2f

};
```

- Is it important that I do use shaders?
- How do I move my vbo vertixes without directly messing with the vertex Array?
- Where exactly do I define and draw my Graphic Objects correctly?
- How is moving objects done usually in modern OpenGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Trying to use the fixed pipeline (no shaders), is no longer recommended, but is still possible (the GPU's emulate it).
- You can still use opengl 1 syntax (glTranslatef etc)
- Before glDrawArrays. You will need to setup the appropriate matrices as always.
- Normally they are done by the user specifying their own model/view/projection matrices, and sending them to a shader to compute the output. The mesh data for static meshes is generally not touched (so you can reuse it etc..)

Comment: I would prefer using moders openGL without glBegin() and glEnd() or any other old methods. So do I define these matrices from inside the shaders and use them there? Do you by anychance have a code example or something? I have found some tutorials but I find them them to be confusing.

Comment: you can, but generally people define them outside and pass them to the shader.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pE9ZDNcg3kw

This guy has 11 tutorials, it's where I learnt a lot of stuff, and also this site is good (although it also covers deprecated OpenGL at the start):
http://www.songho.ca/opengl/